# Nuxt3 Default lay not rendering

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Default layout is not rendering.  created layouts directory and default.vue under it with the below code.  Using Nuxt 3.7.4 with Nitro 2.6.3  and node js 16.13.2

**default.vue**

```
   <template>
      <div>
        Some default layout shared across all pages
        <slot />
      </div>
    </template>
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>

 <NuxtLayout>
    page content
  </NuxtLayout>
 
  </div>
</template>
```

when visiting localhost:3000
only "page content" is getting displayed not sure why its not displaying layout content

Tried restarting doing npm run dev and npm update but its still not displaying default layout content

Comment: did you try by creating a page and use `<NuxtPage />` middle of the `</NuxtLayout>`?

Comment: yes tried that one too its not working

Comment: A [repro] is welcome then.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

default.vue should be in layouts folder in main route

**default.vue**

```
   <template>
      <div>
        <slot />
      </div>
    </template>
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage/>
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Is that ok? did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I created layout directory not under the root but it was under .nuxt directory.  Now it works